# How to `cd` / explore the directory containing the current file?

Tags: filesystem

Sometimes I `gf` to a file in a totally different directory and want to check out that new directory. Is there a way to quickly exit vim *and* `cd` into the directory containing the current buffer?

Comment: If I understand your request, no you can't quit Vim such that you end up in a different directory than you started because the shell is the parent process of the Vim process and a child process can't alter the environment of their parent. It's the same reason you can't do `cd foo` in a shell script and be in  `foo` when the script exits.

Comment: Not directly related but a bit more info about this parent-child stuff (in the context of Vim's `:cd` command) here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22949/11054

Comment: If you want to examine the directory of a newly opened file, you can use netrw like this: `:Vexplore %:h` or start a terminal `:sp | cd %:h | term ++curwin`

Answer (score 5):

I there is a mean but it use a plugin, to solve that simply.

## First approach

If it's only to visualize the current directory, you can use the `:term` command:

```
:term ls %:p:h
```

(filtering result %=current buffer, p=path with file name, h= path only)
It only display the content though.

You can also use the internal file manager with `%:p:h` as a parameter (with `:e`, or `:tabnew` or `:sp` or `:vsp` command):

```
:e %:p:h
```

That open the default file manager inside vim in this specific place. With that you can perform some actions (navigate, delete, copy, paste or modify some files)

## With lf (file explorer with integrated terminal)

In my case, I use a [plugin](https://github.com/ptzz/lf.vim) that integrate `lf` (my favorite terminal file explorer) as vim's internal file explorer. Luckily, `lf` as integrated terminal and can also lauch some shell (as bash, zsh, etc.)

Even outside of vim, it's a good and customizable tui.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This generally can't be done, as the current directory is in a way part of the running environment of a running process and a process typically can't change the running environment of its parent process (in other words, Vim can't affect the shell that spawned it.)

(This is similar to why shell scripts generally can't set environment variables on the shell that spawned them, which is also something that comes up quite frequently.)

There are ways you can set up Vim and the shell to actually implement something like this, but you typically need to prepare the shell for it. In general you should replace the way you call Vim with a function that allows the shell to set up a communication channel so that Vim can tell it to change directories.

A little more specifically, you would create a shell function named `vim` (and possibly others called `vi`, `view`, `vimdiff`, etc. if you want this to work on all ways Vim can be invoked.) This function would set up a way for Vim to send the shell a directory name to `cd` into when done. For example, setting up a temporary file somewhere. Then the function would invoke the real Vim, passing it this communication channel (for example, through an environment variable with the path to the file where Vim could write.) Then you could set up Vim mappings, commands or autocmd's that would write a directory name to that file. Once you leave Vim, the shell function would inspect the file to see if Vim wrote to it and then run `cd` to move to the appropriate directory.

I find that tends to be pretty clunky, but it's definitely doable.

There are better alternatives though. You can start a new shell from inside Vim, with the `:sh` command. When you do so, the new shell will be created under Vim's current directory (see Vim's `:cd` command and also the `'autochdir'` setting.) Recent versions of Vim can also run a shell inside a Vim window, with the `:term` command, and that shell will also be started under Vim's current directory. So rather than trying to affect the shell that launched Vim, you could consider starting a new one from inside Vim?

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do it like this `:cd %:p:h | cd ..` than you can use `telescope.nvim` for example to select files.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I'm having trouble following your answer: `:cd %:p:h` should already take Vim to the directory containing the current file (`:cd ..` not needed). And treesitter has nothing do with selecting files, AFAIK. Perhaps you meant to mention a file explorer or browser?

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you. I just now saw I should have wrote `telescope.nvim` not treesiter I will edit my answer, sorry about that.

Comment: As I understood question is about setting parent directory of the directory containing the current file as a cwd. For example your cwd in Vim is `/pdf/books` and you have `file.c` opened which is located in `/my/projects/lib` than `:cd %:d:h` will take Vim to `/my/projects/lib` yes, but if you do `:cd %:d:h | cd ..` than current working directory is `/my/projects`. telescope.nvim is very useful but it cannot go directory up it only searches in current one, so with the above command entered first you can for example use it to search everything in `/my/projects` instead of in `/my/projects/lib`.

Comment: Q says directory containing the current file (buffer). Also, if you did want to go up a level, `:cd %:p:h | Explore ..` should work.

Comment: Yes you are right Q was about directory containing the current buffer, I wasn't paying enough attention as parent of a parent is something I needed to set up for me just before I answered. `:cd %:p:h | Explore ..` will work also but I don't think it will set a directory one level up as a cwd though.