# Effect of changing directories in a vim command

Tags: vimscript, command-line

When executing a vim command, such as the following:

```
:w!<CR>:!cd %:p:h
```

What is the effect after the command is finished? Is the new `cwd` the directory that I've `cd`'ed into? Or does that only last for the duration of the command?

Comment: Why would you want to `cd` to a different directory running in an external subprocess from Vim? That does not seem to make any sense. Rather use `:cd` or `:lcd` or `:tcd` or `:set autochdir`

Comment: Related: [Why does !cd not change the directory](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22947/why-does-cd-not-change-the-directory/22949#22949) Note that in your example the directory is not (directly) changed by a "Vim command" it's changed by a shell command in a different process (child).